# How to make a ToC with partial links

Tags: publishing, formatting, table-of-contents, kdp

For KDP, I want to create a table of contents with links for chapters (header 1) only but no links for subtitles (header 2) within chapters. The purpose is to shorten the table of contents, as I have a long list of subtitles. With Word, it automatically creates TOC links for both chapters and subtitles. How can I achieve what I want in Word or other free or less expensive apps or services? I've seen multiple Kindle books with such a TOC.

Here is an example of a TOC I want to make:
Chapter 1 (Header 1) <- with a link
Subtitle 1 / Subtitle 2 / Subtitle 3... <- without links
Chapter 2 (Header 1) <- with a link
Subtitle 1 / Subtitle 2 / Subtitle 3... <- without links

Answer (score 0):

There is a free tool called Sigil (https://sigil-ebook.com/sigil/) that might be able to do what you want. I haven't used it since 2015, but back then, it was pretty good at making a table of contents.

Comment: Thank you @Paul for your comment. I'll take a look at Sigil.